# PEAR: Mail not working

Tags: php, html, web, pear

This seems to not work. My webhost claims to have PEAR installed. Does anybody spot any mistakes? I do have every var/field correct. But yet, when this runs, it stops the loading of the rest of the php html page.

```
<?php
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    require_once "Mail.php";

    $from = "No Reply <redacted@redacted.redacted>";
    $to = "redacted";
    $subject = "Hi!";
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

    $host = "redacted.redacted.redacted";
    $username = "redacted@redacted.redacted";
    $password = "---";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Subject' => $subject);

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
        array ('host' => $host,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp -> send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        echo("<p>" . $mail -> getMessage() . "</p>");
    } else {
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide the error you are receiving?

Comment: It's not echoing any errors. It's just refusing to load the rest of the HTML below and send the mail.

Comment: Could you enable error reporting then? Debugging without a stacktrace, requires you to just dump n die. So it's almost impossible to help you any further.

Comment: error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: I don't know how I fixed it, but I just rewrote the entire thing, which is what it sometimes takes :)